# Laravel Migrate Specific File(s) from Migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

Hi read all the included documentation here in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations.

Is there a way on how to migrate a certain migration file (1 migration only), cause right now every time there is a change I use `php artisan migrate:refresh` and all fields are getting reset.

Comment: PSA: Please stop adding answers that are just slight variations on `php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php`

Comment: The answer to the question asked is elsewhere, but the real problem is use of `artisan migrate:refresh` which is designed to wipe out the database and start again. It is **not** part of normal application maintenance like `artisan migrate` is.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

First you should create one `migration` file for your table like:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('fname',255);
            $table->string('lname',255);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

After create **test** folder in **migrations** folder then newly created **migration** moved/copied in **test** folder and run below command in your **terminal/cmd** like:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/test/
```

Comment: php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/test/ worked for me

Comment: If this isn't working out, you have a better answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102197/running-one-specific-laravel-4-migration-single-file

Comment: renaming the migration file worked for me

Comment: To me this looks like the best solution to run specific migrations

Comment: This still works on Laravel 10, thank you very much AddWEb Solution Pvt LTD and Mel

Answer (score 194):

you should add the path to your migration file to refresh just this table and run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Comment: some times it will be 
database/migrations/fileName.php
without the 1st backslash

Comment: It' worth to mention that with a refresh all of your data is gone. You should save the data in your db as an export and import it after the refresh if you wish to keep your data.

Comment: @Taranis Just the data of the table that you are refreshing not all

Comment: For me this is the best solution, I wanted to run a specific migration file

Answer (score 65):

Just look at the `migrations` table in your database, there will be a list of migration file name and batch number value.

Suppose you have following structure,

```
id     migration                                           batch

1      2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table                  1 
2      2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table        1
3      2016_09_07_103432_create_tabel_roles                  1
```

If you want to just rollback `2016_09_07_103432_create_tabel_roles` migration,
change it's migration batch value to 2 which is highest among all and then just execute following.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Here only table with batch value 2 will be rolled back. Now, make changes to that table and run following console command.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Batch value in the `migrations` table defines order of the migrations. when you rollback, migrations that are latest or have highest batch value are rolled back at first and then others. So, you can change the value in database and then rollback a particular migration file.

Although it's not a good idea to change batch number every time because of relationship among the table structure, we can use this case for some cases where single table rollback doesn't violates the integrity among the tables.

Hope you understand.

Comment: @MartneyAcha I'm Happy that you've got solution to your problem Cheers !!

Comment: Nice explanation. If you have a foreign key relationship in your table, that won't work

Comment: @OgbonnaVitalis Thank you, it will be easier way for independent tables. The accepted answer gives exact way to rollback and migrate single table. for multiple independent table it will work.

Answer (score 35):

if you use tab for autocomplete

```
php artisan migrate --path='./database/migrations/2019_12_31_115457_create_coworking_personal_memberships_table.php'
```

Answer (score 26):

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/2020_04_10_130703_create_test_table.php
```

**Note** :
after `--path` no `/` before

Comment: This is so strange I have used this command before but for some reason I can't run a specific file but entire base `php artisan migrate` runs fine and migrates the same file.

Answer (score 17):

You can run command like this

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2020_04_10_130703_create_test_table.php
```

Answer (score 15):

## For Specific File run this command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path="database/migrations/Your_Migration_File_Name_table.php"
```

Here  `--file=`  is for location of your file and `migrate:refresh` will empty your table data

#### If you want to empty all table's data from database then run

`php artisan migrate:refresh` command.

Comment: php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/2021_10_16_071955_create_aaa_table.php

not "\" it should be "/" and without "

Answer (score 14):

You can only run this command in your terminal

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/2020_10_01_164611_create_asset_info_table.php
```

After migrations you should put the particular file name. or if you have any folder inside migration then just add that folder name after the migration.

Like this

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/yourfolder/2020_10_01_164611_create_asset_info_table.php
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to put the file(s) into a new directory (ex:selected) and then apply

```
php artisan migrate  --path=/database/migrations/selected
```

if you need rollback:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback  --path=/database/migrations/selected
```

**Note:**

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

this will rollback and then migrate all the migrations files in the default directory (/database/migrations)

Comment: No need to create a new directory you can put directly the file name like '--path=/database/migrations/fileName.php' .

Comment: as of laravel 5.6, glob() functions where used which I think only works with directory which makes this answer also correct in a way.

Answer (score 9):

```
php artisan help migrate
```

You will see the option:

> --path[=PATH]          The path to the migrations files to be executed

By the way, you can probably indicate the root folder of the file that you want to migrate:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/sample.php
```

Or, You can create a new folder in migrations, then migrate all the migration files you want inside it:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/new_folder
```

Comment: you just missed a 's'. It should be 'migrations'!
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/new_folder

Comment: php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/new_folder/
need the last '/'

Answer (score 9):

Just use the --path flag. You don't need to use rollback, refresh, or any other command.
Example:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/migration_file_name.php
```

Answer (score 8):

Get the actual file name and path of the migration and run the command like below

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2021_10_03_071450_create_reset_codes_table.php
```

Answer (score 7):

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

You don't have to refresh for migration, because **refresh** means  : *Rollback* *all migrations and run them all again*.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to post another solution, which i think is worth mentioning.

1. Find row with your migration name in migrations table and DELETE it. 
   It should look like this: 2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table
2. Remove your table from database e.g. DROP TABLE oauth_auth_codes
3. Run php artisan migrate

It will migrate only the table you need, and won't touch anything else

Answer (score 6):

Correction- remove slash before the database

```
$ php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/migration.php
```

Comment: Nothing to migrate.

Comment: @zod use refresh: 
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/migration.php

Answer (score 6):

**Specific Table Migration**

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only rollback:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

You can specify how many migrations to roll back to using the 'step' option:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
```

Some tricks are available here:

[Rollback one specific migration in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287896/rollback-one-specific-migration-in-laravel)

Answer (score 4):

Delete the table and remove its record from migration table.

After that you just run migration again:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can simply delete migration file name from your database, in "migrations" table and then run : **php artitsan migration**

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/<migration file here>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create another table, just create a new migration file. It'll will work.

If you create a migration named `users_table` with `id, first_name, last_name`. You can create a migration file like

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name',255);
            $table->string('last_name',255);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

If you want to add another field like "status" without migrate:refresh. You can create another migration file like "add_status_filed_to_users_table"

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->integer('status');
    });
}
```

And don't forget to add the rollback option:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('status');
    });
}
```

And when you run the migration with `php artisan migration`, just migrate the new migration file.

But if you add field "status" into the first migration file (users_table) and run migration. It's nothing to migrate. You need to run `php artisan migrate:refresh`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

**Use:** `--path=database/migrations/your_migration_file_name.php`

**Examples:**

php artisan **migrate:refresh** `--path=database/migrations/your_migration_file_name.php`

php artisan **migrate:rollback** `--path=database/migrations/your_migration_file_name.php`

php artisan **migrate** `--path=database/migrations/your_migration_file_name.php`

References: [Genarate laravel migration](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#generating-migrations)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the --path= option to define the specific sub-folder you're wanting to execute and place specific migrations in there.

Alternatively you would need to remove reference and tables from the DB and migrations tables which isn't ideal :/

Answer (score 1):

install this package

https://github.com/nilpahar/custom-migration/

and run this command.

```
php artisan migrate:custom -f migration_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/fileName.php
```

Just follow the instruction execute this commant file name here should be your migration table name
Example:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2020_02_21_101937_create_jobs_table.php
```

Answer (score -1):

First you should to make the following commands:

Step 1:

```sh
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Step 2:

```sh
php artisan migrate
```

Your table will be back in database .

Comment: It would be more helpful if you put small description to each step. This will help in understanding the user what actually is happening. This looks like a cheat-code which magically make things work, but outcome might be disastorous in some cases.

Comment: Please read question carefully, the person asked for only one table, your method will rollback all migrations and then create all tables.

Also `php artisan migration:refresh` serves the same.

Answer (score -1):

you can also migrate again migrated table but first you need to go in database migration table and delete row that specific migration name.
and then hit php artisan migrate