# Refresh laravel migration for specific table

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-migrate

Can I run `php artisan migrate:refresh` for specific table?
Or can I refresh specific table migration in general?

I tried this:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/selected/
```

But it's not working!

Comment: Maybe this one can help you? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-execute-a-specific-table-migration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Migrate Specific File(s) from Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473624/laravel-migrate-specific-files-from-migrations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running one specific Laravel migration (single file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102197/running-one-specific-laravel-migration-single-file)

Answer (score 7):

For Specific File run this command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --path="database\migrations\Your_Migration_File_Name_table.php"
```

Here  `--file=`  is for location of your file and `migrate:refresh` will empty your table data

If you want to empty all table's data from database then run

`php artisan migrate:refresh` command.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

The `--table` and `--create` options may also be used to indicate the name of the table and whether the migration will be creating a new table. These options pre-fill the generated migration stub file with the **specified table**

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
php artisan make:migration add_votes_to_users_table --table=user
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations

Comment: The is not what OP has asked, technically correct answer but does not remotely relate to the question in hand.